# neural network in python that I can't get it to learn

Tags: python, neural-network

I have code for 2 neural networks that I can't get them to learn.
(The assignment is to check if a point in the matrix is inside the Star of David or not)
I manage to bring her to a state of certain percentages of success in the first epoch and then in all the other epochs there is no change.It seems to me that the problem is somewhere in the update of the weights.

Any advice on how to make it learn?

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
# Define input values
bank = np.linspace(0, 1000)
# Define activation function:
def sigmoid(x):
    y = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
    return y
# Derivative:
def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))
# Set the shape for Star of David; set coordinates for two triangles in the shape of a Star of David
# Vectors for 1st inverted triangle:
verts1 = [
    (500, 0),
    (0, 600),
    (1000, 600),
    (0., 0.)  # ignored
]
# Vectors for second upright triangle:
verts2 = [
    (500, 1000),
    (0, 300),
    (1000, 300),
    (0., 0.)  # ignored
]
# Codes for path formation:
codes = [
    Path.MOVETO,
    Path.LINETO,
    Path.LINETO,
    Path.CLOSEPOLY,
]
# Final path definition
triangle1 = Path(verts1, codes)
triangle2 = Path(verts2, codes)
# Function to plot shape. Just remove from comment to make it work.
# fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# patch1 = patches.PathPatch(triangle1, facecolor='orange', lw=2)
# patch2 = patches.PathPatch(triangle2, facecolor='orange', lw=2)
# ax.add_patch(patch1)
# ax.add_patch(patch2)
# ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
# ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
# plt.show()
# Set variable for random number
random_number = rd.choice(bank)
# Set function to determine whether given point is inside shape
def contains(point):
    if triangle1.contains_point(point) and triangle2.contains_point(point):
        return True
    return False
# Generate a set of random points. number = length of set
def set_of_points(number):
    set = []
    for i in range(number):
        set.append([rd.choice(bank), rd.choice(bank)])
    return set
# Function for building a list of labels for a set of points
def in_out(point_set):
    labels = []
    for point in point_set:
        if contains(point):
            labels.append(1)
        else:
            labels.append(0)
    return labels
#################################################################
# Error function
def error(output, label):
    c = 1 / 2 * ((output - label) ** 2)
    return c
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self,input):
        #for question 1:/ Random weights for 2 layer network
        self.weights = np.random.random((2, 1))
        #for question 2: / Random weights for 4 layer network
        self.weights1 = np.random.randint(0,1000,(2, 6))  # weights for the first intermediate layer
        self.weights2 = np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(6, 2))  # weights for the second intermediate layer
        self.weights3 = np.random.randint(0,1000,(2, 1))  # weights for the output layer
        #print(self.weights1)
        self.output = self.forward1(input)
        self.output2 =np.dot(self.weights1.T, input.T)
        self.output3 = np.dot(self.weights2.T,self.output2)
    # Forward pass for 2 layer network
    def forward1(self, input):
        output = sigmoid(np.dot(input, self.weights))
        return output
    # Back propagation of error for 2 layer network
    def back_prop1(self, learning_rate, output, label, input):
        w_new = []
        for i in range(len(input)):
            #new_weight = self.weights[i] - learning_rate * ((output - label) * sigmoid_derivative(input[i] * self.weights[i]) * input[i])
            new_weight = self.weights[i] - learning_rate * ((output - label) * sigmoid_derivative(output) * input[i])
            w_new.append(new_weight)
        self.weights = np.array(w_new)
    # Forward pass for 4 layer network
    def forward2(self, input):
        output1 = sigmoid(np.dot(input.T, self.weights1))
        output2 = sigmoid(np.dot(output1, self.weights2))
        output = sigmoid(np.dot(output2, self.weights3))
        return output
    # Backpropagation for 4 layer network
    def back_prop2(self, learning_rate, output, label, input):
        for i in range(len(self.weights3)):
            #update of 3rd layers weigets
            delta3 = (output - label) * sigmoid_derivative(output)
            new_weight3 = self.weights3[i] - learning_rate * np.dot(delta3, self.output3[i])
            self.weights3[i] = new_weight3
            #for i in range(len(self.weights2)):
            for j in range(len(self.weights2[0])):
                # update of 2nd layers weights
                delta2 = np.dot(delta3, self.weights3.T) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output2)
                new_weight2 = self.weights2[i][j] - learning_rate * np.dot(self.output2.T, delta2[:, j])
                self.weights2[i][j] = new_weight2
                for k in range(len(self.weights1)):
                    #update of 1th layers weigets
                    delta1 = np.dot(delta2.T, self.weights2) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output)
                    new_weight1 = self.weights1[k][j] - learning_rate * np.dot(input.T, delta1[k,:])
                    self.weights1[k][j] = new_weight1
# This function measures accuracy and loss rates for the test batch of points
def test(network, inputs, labels, quest):
    loss = []
    correct = 0
    if quest == 1:
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            output = network.forward1(inputs[i])
            loss.append(error(output, labels[i]))
            if output > 500:
                prediction = 1
            else:
                prediction = 0
            if prediction == labels[i]:
                correct += 1
    else:
        for i in range(len(inputs)):
            output = network.forward2(inputs[i])
            loss.append(error(output, labels[i]))
            if output > 800:
                prediction = 1
            else:
                prediction = 0
            if prediction == labels[i]:
                correct += 1
    accuracy = correct / len(labels)
    actual_loss = sum(loss) / len(loss)
    return actual_loss, accuracy
# This function is supposed to train the neural network using the training set of points
def train(network, inputs, labels, epochs, learning_rate, quest):
    loss = []
    for j in range(epochs):
        rd.seed(j)  # Initialize random number generator with epoch as the seed
        errors_in_epoch = []
        if quest == 1:
            for i in range(len(inputs)):
                output = network.forward1(inputs[i])
                network.back_prop1(learning_rate, output, labels[i], inputs[i])
                errors_in_epoch.append(error(output, labels[i]))
        else:
            for i in range(len(inputs)):
                output = network.forward2(inputs[i])
                network.back_prop2(learning_rate, output, labels[i], inputs[i])
                errors_in_epoch.append(error(output, labels[i]))
        _, accuracy = test(network, inputs, labels, quest)
        print(quest, "Q-epochs:", j + 1, "======== accuracy:", accuracy * 100, "%")
        print(quest, "Q-epochs:", j + 1, "======== loss:", sum(errors_in_epoch) / len(errors_in_epoch))
        loss.append(sum(errors_in_epoch) / len(errors_in_epoch))
        #print(output)
    return loss
# Values:
input = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (1, 2))
print(input)
net = NeuralNetwork(input) # Initialize object type
points = set_of_points(1000) # Initialize random points
labels = in_out(points) # Generate labels for random point set
points_train = np.array(points[:10]) # Training set of points
points_test = np.array(points[11:]) # Test set of points
labels_train = np.array(labels[:10]) # Labels for training function
labels_test = np.array(labels[11:]) # labels for testing function
learning_rate = 26
epochs = 5
#This function is generate graph 
def plot_points(network, inputs, labels):
    x1 = inputs[:, 0]
    x2 = inputs[:, 1]
    output = network.forward2(inputs)
    diff = output - labels
    colors = np.where(diff == 0, 'green', 'red').tolist()
    plt.scatter(x1, x2, c=colors.flatten())
    plt.xlabel('x1')
    plt.ylabel('x2')
    plt.title('Points Visualization')
    plt.show()
print('Question 1: ', train(net, points_train, labels_train, epochs, learning_rate, 1))
print(test(net, points_train, labels_train, 1))
print('Question 2: ', train(net, points_train, labels_train, epochs, learning_rate, 2))
print(test(net, points_train, labels_train, 2))
# After training the network, you can use the plot_points function to visualize the points:
#plot_points(net, points_test, labels_test)
</blink>
```

The weights are updated very negligibly between epochs
the code step by step:

1. The code begins by importing necessary libraries such as `numpy` for numerical computations, `random` for generating random numbers, and `matplotlib` for visualization.
2. Next, the code defines the activation function `sigmoid` and its derivative `sigmoid_derivative`. The sigmoid function is commonly used as an activation function in neural networks.
3. The code defines the shape of the Star of David using the `verts1` and `verts2` variables, which contain the coordinates for two triangles. It also includes the codes for path formation.
4. There is a commented section of code that uses `matplotlib` to plot the shape of the Star of David. If you uncomment and run this section, it will display the shape on a graph.
5. The code defines a function `contains` to check whether a given point is inside the shape of the Star of David. It uses the `contains_point` method from `matplotlib.path.Path` to determine if a point is inside each triangle.
6. The `set_of_points` function generates a set of random points within a specified range.
7. The `in_out` function generates labels (1 or 0) for a set of points based on whether they are inside the Star of David shape.
8. The code defines an error function that calculates the error between the network output and the desired label.
9. The `NeuralNetwork` class is defined, which represents a neural network. It has two versions: one for the 2-layer network (question 1) and one for the 4-layer network (question 2).
10. In the `NeuralNetwork` class, the `forward1` method performs the forward pass for the 2-layer network, while the `forward2` method performs the forward pass for the 4-layer network. These methods calculate the output of the network based on the input and current weights.
11. The `back_prop1` method implements backpropagation for the 2-layer network, updating the weights based on the error between the output and the label.
12. The `back_prop2` method implements backpropagation for the 4-layer network, updating the weights of each layer based on the error.
13. The `test` function measures the accuracy and loss rates for a given test batch of points. It calculates the output of the network for each point and compares it with the corresponding label to determine the accuracy.
14. The `train` function trains the neural network using a training set of points. It performs multiple epochs of forward pass, backpropagation, and updates the weights. It also calls the `test` function to evaluate the network's performance during training.
15. The code generates a random input, creates an instance of the `NeuralNetwork` class, and generates a set of random points with labels for training and testing.
16. Finally, the code calls the `train` function with the appropriate arguments to train the neural network and prints the loss and accuracy during training. It also calls the `test` function to evaluate the network's performance on the training set.

Overall, the code implements a basic neural network and trains it to classify points inside or outside the shape of a Star of David. It uses backpropagation to update the weights and measures the network's performance using accuracy and loss metrics.

Comment: Do you check your gradients?

Comment: @ConventionalProgrammer Can you explain what settings you meant?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the gradient descent algorithm. As far as I can see, the weights and activations blow up so that there occurs overflow in the sigmoid function. Maybe you can try to initialize your weights with different values and adjust the learning rate accordingly. I would suggest you monitor the gradient matrix explicitly either declaring it as global in the functions or printing out to the console.